# Execute script from MySQL workbench EER model?

Tags: mysql-workbench, eer-model

There's a facility in MySQL Workbench's EER Modelling mode to write an SQL script that's stored with the model.  But I've looked all over the place and can't see any way of executing such a script, other than by copying and pasting it into a window of the query mode.  There's a menu item Scripting/Run Script, but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.  Surely there must be some application of the scripts section of the model beyond just storing SQL text?

Comment: are you thinking about the forward engineering feature?

Comment: I just want a way to distribute arbitrary setup code with my EER model (in this case to set up users with non-wildcard hostnames, which is apparently impossible with the standard features of workbench).  Ideally, it would run during forward engineering and/or synchronization, but failing that anything that's easy to do would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running arbitrary SQL code during forward engineering or synchronization is not possible. The only code that gets executed is the sql to create the objects and to fill tables with data specified in the **Inserts** section of the table editor.

Running an sql script in general is of course possible and also trivial. Simply open a connection to your server (you should have one created on the home screen, if not do this first). Then in the editor toolbar there's a button to open a script. Use that to open the file (if you have a separate sql file). If you want to run code that is stored in the model (as SQL file) you have to copy/paste it over.

Comment: Thanks. It seems odd that there's a mechanism to store SQL code in the model but no way of executing it, but it's nice to have confirmation that I'm not missing something obvious. :)